# Datatables column definitions and reorder not applied after reload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, datatables

I've have many processes using the same data that gets regular updates while a user is on a page. Now I want to use datatables to show this data.

I also use the ColReorder plugin.

The problem is that I don't understand how I can force datatables to 'reload' this local var with new data.

there is is also a bunch of definitions in the "aoColums" setting, using some of the datafields for images and so on.

I changed some of the data in the dat var. The tried to force datatables to put it in the table. No luck. I can't find a decent example or function in the api to use.

if I try to use oTable.fnClearTable() and the oTable.fnAddData(data) the data gets loaded, but somehow the ColReorder is not aplied.

```
myTable = $('#myTable').dataTable({
    "aoColumns": [ ... ],
    "aaSorting": [[1, 'asc']],
    "aaData": data,
    "sScrollY": 200,
    "sScrollX": "100%",
    "sScrollXInner": "150%",
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sDom": 'R<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>',
    "iFixedColumns": 3,
    "oColReorder": {
        "aiOrder": [ 0, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 9 ]
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**
I've made a working [jsFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aKuHM/4/) with the whole problem explained. Take a look and have a go!

Comment: are you using a json array?

Comment: No, its a normal array, with arrays for each row. (there are no field names, just the data [ [ cell1, cell2], [cell3, cell4] ]. Do you have it working with json?

Comment: Did you see the documentation for js arrays? http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

Comment: Yes, I actually build such a thing, the problem is that I want datatables to reload the supplied js_array. If I need to make a function that iterates over it row by row, thats also OK

Comment: please see the jsFiddle in the edit for more details (working example with problem!)

Comment: I think i accomplish what you want.....let me answer and post my fiddle version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read about your problem....i take another approach to your problem(it's always about dom manipulation xD)...my anwer it's not the smartest, but i think it works.

- I put datatables manipulation inside a function, and add a div no the table
- Then i call that function
- On update i empty the div and add the same html that table have before datatbles manipulation and fill
- Then a call the function to draw the whole datatables again, in that way ColReorder plugin works with the updated data.

PS: Here is the updated fiddle for more details : http://jsfiddle.net/aKuHM/5

Now the table looks like this:

```
<div class="Example" id="Example">
<table id="myTable" class="datatable">
 <thead>
 </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
 <tfoot>
 </tfoot>
</table>
</div>
```

And your JS its loading on the head and looks this way:

```
data = [
            ['cell1', 'cell2','cell3','cell4','cell5','cell6','cell17', 'cell8', 'cell9', 'cell10'],
            ['cell1', 'cell2','cell3','cell4','cell5','cell6','cell17', 'cell8', 'cell9', 'cell10'],
            ['cell1', 'cell2','cell3','cell4','cell5','cell6','cell17', 'cell8', 'cell9', 'cell10'],
        ];
        function Saludos(){
        $(function(){
            myTable = $('#myTable').dataTable({
                "aoColumns": [
                    {"sTitle":"col0", "bSearchable": false, "bVisible": true},
                    {"sTitle":"col1", "bSearchable": false, "bVisible": true},
                    {"sTitle":"col2", "bSearchable": true, "bVisible": true},
                    {"sTitle":"col3", "bSearchable": true, "bVisible": true},
                    {"sTitle":"col4", "bSearchable": true, "bVisible": true},
                    {"sTitle":"col5", "bSearchable": false, "bVisible": true},
                    {"sTitle":"col6", "bSearchable": true, "bVisible": true},
                    {"sTitle":"col7", "bSearchable": false, "bVisible": true},
                    {"sTitle":"col8", "bSearchable": true, "bVisible": true,
                        "mRender": function (data, type, row){
                            return '<b><i>'+ row[8] +'</i></b>';
                        }
                    },
                    {"sTitle":"col9", "bSearchable": false, "bVisible": false},
                ],    
                "aaSorting": [[8, 'asc']],
                "aaData": data,
                "sScrollY": 200,
                "sScrollX": "100%",
                "sScrollXInner": "150%",
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "sDom": 'R<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>',
                "iFixedColumns": 3,
                "oColReorder": {
                    "aiOrder": [ 0, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 9 ]
                }
            });

            $('#updatebutton').click(function(){
                updateTable();
            });
        });

        }
        Saludos();
        function updateTable(){
            data[1][8] = "even bolder";
            $('.Example').empty();
            $("#Example").html("<table id='myTable' class='datatable'><thead></thead>  <tbody></tbody><tfoot></tfoot></table>");
            Saludos();
            console.log(data);

        }
```

Comment: Hi Robert! Although I think that throwing away the table, recreate it is a very bad way of 'updating' things. It is a sollution that works. Even in jsFiddle it works realy fast. If you use "bStateSave": true, it even retains changes between rebuilds.

Comment: Yes i think the same man....but it's the only thing i could think....and, like you said, works fast, and it's the only way to work with the plugin; bassically because you where using 2 different ways to populate the table....it's haves to be done in the same way, the load and the update....it's haves to be a more elegant way but, if you think that my answer works, dont forget to mark it as correct....saludos ;)

Comment: sure, will do when I implement in the site. Now the search works buggy after update. Not in your example... bit weird...

Comment: I've solved the issues: even after rebuilding, the format of the data (array of arrays or array of objects) needs to be the same for the table (breaks search otherwise). You need to clean up other events you coupled before you recreate the table (for example the row expand).